# Applying custom function across multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to pandas and having trouble even stating the problem, much less solving the it. If have a pandas DataFrame as such:

```
m = [[1,2,3], [4,2,4], [3,4,5], [2,3,4], [1,5,3], [4,2,5], [3,4,3], [2,1,4], [1,2,3], [4,3,3], [3,2,5], [2,2,4]]
d = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=['key', 'val1', 'val2'])
```

I would like to apply a custom function to each row (for example, val1 ** val2). Then I would like to aggregate by key (for example, average). The end result would look something like this:

```
   key  result
0    1   47.00
1    2   32.67
2    3  373.33
3    4   19.00
```

I know that I could do this by using loops, but I was hoping to achieve this in the most python/pandas way: by grouping by the key and then applying the custom function across all columns. Or maybe it would be better to apply a custom function across all rows, and then apply a groupby by key with mean aggregation?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Create new `Series` by custom function and `groupby` by `Series` - `d['key']` with aggregate `mean`:

```
d = (d['val1'] ** d['val2']).groupby(d['key']).mean().reset_index(name='mean')
```

Or create new column first and then aggregate `mean`:

```
d['col'] = (d['val1'] ** d['val2'])
d = d.groupby('key')['col'].mean().reset_index(name='mean')

print (d)
   key        mean
0    1   47.000000
1    2   32.666667
2    3  373.333333
3    4   25.000000
```